# May I get the current user in preUpdate (the atlassian bitbucket plugin)

Tags: bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

According to bitbucket server reference https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/javadoc/5.3.0/spi/reference/com/atlassian/bitbucket/hook/repository/PreRepositoryHook.html

In the function

```
public RepositoryHookResult preUpdate(PreRepositoryHookContext context, RepositoryHookRequest request)
```

How can I get the current user,or who are pushing the code? NOT the commit's author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this example https://github.com/tomasbjerre/simple-bitbucket-commit-checker/blob/master/src/main/java/se/bjurr/sbcc/SbccPreReceiveRepositoryHook.java

You need to pass to your hook `AuthenticationContext` object and to use `getCurrentUser()` method